# mongodb injection possibility

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, security

I'm new to mongodb and I'm using this query in server side (node js),

```
collection.find({},function(e,crimes){
    collection.col.aggregate([{$match: req.body},
      {$group: { _id: "$district",  count: {$sum: 1}}}
    ],function(e,docs){
        console.log(docs);
        res.render('postResults', {
            "output" : docs
        });
   });
});
```

in the line `collection.col.aggregate([{$match: req.body}` I directly inject an object sent from the client side with **`req.body`**.

I want to know if this approach leads to a security vulnerability like **sql injection**. If yes, how serious is the vulnerability? Is it possible for an attacker to do operations other than read-only ones with this?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Are you using Mongoose?

Comment: I'm using `monk`. @unobf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can inject a different query by changing `req.body`. For example, if you were looking up a specific crime, your `req.body` might look like `{ "_id" : "123456" }`. But I could instead send `{ }`. Then every document would match and the aggregation pipeline would process every document, which might be sufficient to cause performance problems. Since the aggregation pipeline never alters the original documents, you can't change the data, so it's a read-only attack but it could still be used to choke up your servers with collection scans and large-volume aggregation pipelines.

Comment: @wdberkley - the same could be said of any query that returns a lot of data, the approach itself does not introduce a security vulnerability of the same sort as a SQL injection

Comment: Thanks. If I send only values like `123456` and inject them at the server side, instead sending objects like `{ "_id" : "123456" }` for `$match` it will be safer, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, if your query is `{ "a" : myValue }`, where `myValue` is a variable whose value you get from the client, you might expect to receive an integer and therefore do a query like `{ "a" : 2 }`, but someone could instead send an object like `{ "$gte" : 2 }`. You should also enforce the type of `myValue` to prevent unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

You might check these out to learn the issue;

1. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_NoSQL_injection
2. http://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb.html

Solutions;

1. Don't use a function with a `$where` operator if the users interact with MongoDB.
2. There are some tools to prevent the *injection* issues;
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/content-filter
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sanitize
3. Be aware of [CSRF](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "No", this does not cause any Query injection issues because your Node.js server has already turned the HTTP request into a JSON object and therefore any data entered by the user is a JavaScript string that is part of this JSON object. You are not concatenating strings like you might do in other languages that make them vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks. Even though an attacker can try to reduce performance,the attacker cannot alter the query..